# psql: error: connection to server on socket

Tags: server, postgresql

After installation, I try to run the program also I tried many
suggestions that have been published here but couldn't fix the problem :(

Ubuntu 20.04

root@root:~$ psql

psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this error occasionally in the past because my postgresql.conf file is set up to look for the socket file in a different directory. On our servers, we have the following setting:

```
unix_socket_directories = '/tmp,/var/run/postgresql'    
# comma-separated list of directories
```

Your Postgres database will fail to boot if it cannot find the path properly to the socket files. So on my server, when the /var/run/postgresql directory was missing, it would prevent pg_ctl start from working. The error would show in my log file.

Based on this, check your value for the "unix_socket_directories" parameter, and make sure it is not referencing a directory that does not exist.

EDIT:
To fix the problem on my Ubuntu server, I simply issued a mkdir command and created the missing directory, and made sure (chown/chmod) that the postgres user was able to access that area.

Comment: psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
 Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?