# psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused

Tags: networking, server, postgresql

I had a problem here [psql: error: connection to server on socket](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1497006/psql-error-connection-to-server-on-socket/1497025#1497025)

Hello Everyone, I checked a lot on the Internet to fix the problem but couldn't do anything.

First of all, I changed my configuration based on here.

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port= 5432
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main'
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql,/tmp'    # comma-separated list >
                                        # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_group = ''                  # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_permissions = 0777          # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                                        # (change requires restart)
bonjour = off                           # advertise server via Bonjour
                                        # (change requires restart)
bonjour_name = ''               
ali@ali:~$ sudo systemctl restart postgresql
ali@ali:~$ psql
$ psql
psql: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
ali@ali:~$ export PGHOST=localhost
ali@ali:~$ psql
psql: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

my hba file:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
host   all             postgres                                peer 
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0              md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             192.168.1.0/24          md5
```

ali@ali:$~ sudo ufw allow 5432
ali@ali:$~ sudo ufw status
WARN: /etc is world writable!
Status: active

To                         Action      From

---

5432/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
5432                       ALLOW       Anywhere
5433                       ALLOW       Anywhere
5432/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5432 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5433 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

ali@ali:$~ netstat -lntu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46589         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:36287         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37915         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40483         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42069           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2628          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::1716                 :::*                    LISTEN
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42069           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:60941           0.0.0.0:*
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*
udp6       0      0 :::56614                :::*
udp6       0      0 :::1716                 :::*

It seems port 5432 is not open, I couldn't open the port anyway :(
I also changed the permissions by chmod to 777
I don't know what should i do.
Ubuntu version 20.04.03
Postgradesql version: 9.3
I had the same problem when I installed postgradesql 14 or 15 or 16 ...

Comment: What's your configuration?

Comment: listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432

Comment: You'll need a lot more information for anyone to help you.  Can you update your question with the command you're using to connect to it?  Also, the output of `sudo service postgresql status`.  You might as well also include the version of Ubuntu and PostgreSQL.

Comment: Updated! @Ray 

here you go

Comment: Ah!  So you haven't installed the defaulit version for Ubuntu 20.04?  The default version is [12](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=postgresql). 
 Still should be ok if there were no problems installing. 
 Perhaps you can check if 5432 is being listened to, by using instructions [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-check-if-port-is-in-use-command/)?  In my installation, I have log files in `/var/log/postgresql/`.  Maybe see if there's any information there?

Comment: After the uninstallation, I installed version 15. It seems 5432 is not being listened to. There is nothing on the log file. @Ray Probably I think the problem is in the pg_hba file.

Comment: I'm not an expert with PostgreSQL...  So, unless someone else gives better help, I would suggest you either upgrade your Ubuntu *or* downgrade your PostgreSQL.  So that the program matches the OS.  When the two match, there are many more web pages that you can consult and more people can help you.  Try to get that working and then move up the PostgreSQL version after.  It could be a problem with the `pg_hba.conf` file, but I think you would have incorrect permissions to log in as an error message, and not fail to connect to a port.  Just my guess...

Comment: I updated the Question @ray  ...
Can you help me again?